# Restricting gtkmozembed to load only pages from certain server(s)

Tags: python, gtk

for a Python project I'm using **gtkmozembed MozEmbed()** as a simple HTML-browser. What I'm looking for:

(1) Restricting, which servers are allowed to connect to, e.g. only `http://localhost`.

and/or

(2) A kind of **"onClick()"** function to check if links clicked by user are referring to allowed pages/servers or not.

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: We required something similar 3 years ago and had to switch to WebKit (Gtk/Qt, doesn't realy matter). WebKit has different signals for resource loading / url requests and allows you to intercept.

Comment: @MartinSamson I don't know if this was possible 3 years ago, but now there's a solution, see below.

Answer (score 1):

O.K., this is getting embarrassing. I keep asking questions at stackoverflow and shortly afterwards find the answer elsewhere. Sorry.

Nevertheless, here's the answer:gtkmozembed has a signal called ["open-uri"](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtkmozembed/class-gtkmozembed.html#signal-gtkmozembed--open-uri) which can be connected to a callback function like this:

```
browser = gtkmozembed.MozEmbed()
browser.connect("open-uri", OpenUri)

def OpenUri(mozembed, uri, data=None):
    if uri.startswith('http://localhost/'):
        print "Will now open", uri, "..."
        return False

    print uri, "is not in the list of allowed uris." + "\nLoading denied."
    return True
```

Unless anybody has got a better solution? ...I will use this.

### E D I T:

This solution is **not** 100% save. While users cannot directly open disallowed links, links embedded within source code, like

```
 <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

will still be loaded!

Comment: Thanks for posting your own answer! Too many people forget to do that.

Comment: Don't forget to also accept this answer to know your problem is solved

Comment: @Ancurio I haven't found a 100%-save solution yet. I switched to webkit.